# Android service in background

Tags: java, android, web-services, service, background-process

I have created a webservice and I want to use a android phone as a terminal.
The phone has to check for messages on the webservice every now and then.

Is it possible to create a "background task" or service, that checks a specific webservice every now and then?
Isn't this the way email is working? Should be possible.
If not, how can I create a "push" service, that reaches the android phone?

I have created a simple service, but it only runs for some minutes, and then "stops" talking to the server. Looks like it happens when the screen locks.

I have a class, that extends service. And I override following method.

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(_TAG, "onStart");
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d(_TAG, "running task!! Hello :)");
            try {
                sendSMS();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, 0, 60000);
}
```

Works like a charm, until the display gets locked.

The phone is a HTC Desire S

I'm pretty new to android developement, and don't know the framework therefor.

Regards..

Comment: Do you have any example? Framwork to use? ..

Comment: no framework needed for a simple task like polling. create a background service -> query a url -> parse response -> profit (-> repeat). you have some research ahead of you.

Comment: With all due respect Matt K, instead of helping your comment sounds a lot like "Haha, I know more about this than you and I'm going to prove it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to decide on Pushing data to device or Pulling it from device. Depending upon your decision implementation changes.

You can create Background Service which will keep polling after every x minutes and pulls your data,

Try this blog post http://www.zubha-labs.com/android-services-101-part-1 to learn more about services and also have source code to actually execute.

Or

Use android C2DM http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/ for Pushing it from your server.

Comment: Would like pulling. Do you have any example or tutorial on this?

Comment: Just updated post with example have a look. Also i recommend you reading this blog http://zubhium.posterous.com/whats-the-right-way-to-beta-test-your-mobile overall great pointer about building kick ass android apps.

Answer (score 2):

As the other posters have pointed out it would be more optimal for your app to receive intents via a push based approach, so you're not wasting resources constantly polling.

But if you need to poll and/or execute some code at some specified intervals than the `Alarm Manager` is what you want. You register your app to be invoked at certain points in time, which is when you then fire up your Service to poll for data.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Looks promising. Will look at this later :)

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible to create a background [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html).

However, if the main purpose of the service is to periodically check the server for new messages, it's *much* better for battery life to use a push service.  Google has one called [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/), which is currently free.

Comment: I have been looking at pushing .. I need pulling.